# FileChooserButton behaviour

Tags: gtk, genie

I've been getting a strange behaviour when I connect selection_changed to a
function in a FileChooserButton. With the help of
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689763/the-signal-connect-syntax)
users I now understand the selection_changed syntax. But something weird is
happening when I use it for the second time in the same program.

### Context

My aim is to create a window with two FileChooserButtons and an Entry text
at the end position of the window. The first FileChooserButton helps the
user pick the directory and causes the second FileChooserButton to open at
the directory the user chose in the first one. Up until this point the code
is working perfectly. The entry is also properly drawn and says "Here goes
the filename". The intended behaviour is to change the entry's text upon the
selection of the filename in the second FileChooserButton after checking
whether the file is writable.

The strategy I used was to connect the selection_changed to a function that
takes care of checking wether the file is writable and the change of the
entry's text.

The problem is that the function is never called. I added a debugging dumb
code like:

```
stdout.printf("Checking whether this function is actually called")
```

It never gets printed,thus I suppose the function never gets called. The function in question is the file_changed one below.

```
[indent=4]
uses
    Gtk

class TestWindow:Window
    _file_chooser:FileChooserButton
    _entry:Gtk.Entry

    construct()

        title = "File chooser"
        window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER
        destroy.connect( Gtk.main_quit )

        var folder_chooser = new FileChooserButton("Choose a Folder",FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)
        folder_chooser.set_current_folder( Environment.get_home_dir() )
        folder_chooser.selection_changed.connect( folder_changed )

        _file_chooser = new FileChooserButton("Choose a File",FileChooserAction.OPEN)
        _file_chooser.set_current_folder( Environment.get_home_dir() )

        _file_chooser.selection_changed.connect( file_changed )
        var _entry = new Gtk.Entry()
        _entry.set_text("Here the file name")

        var box = new Box( Orientation.VERTICAL, 0 )
        box.pack_start( folder_chooser, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _file_chooser, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _entry, true, true, 0 )

        add( box )

    def folder_changed( folder_chooser_widget:FileChooser )
        folder:string = folder_chooser_widget.get_uri()
        _file_chooser.set_current_folder_uri( folder )

    def file_changed ( file_chooser_widget: FileChooser )
        stdout.printf(file_chooser_widget.get_filename())

        stdout.printf("Checking whether this function is actually called")

        file:File = File.new_for_uri(file_chooser_widget.get_filename())
        stdout.printf(file_chooser_widget.get_filename())
        info:FileInfo = file.query_info (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE, FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, null)
        writable:bool = info.get_attribute_boolean (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE)
        stdout.printf(writable.to_string())
        if writable is true
            _entry.set_sensitive(false)


init
    Gtk.init( ref args )
    var test = new TestWindow()
    test.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

### Question

- Why the second selection_changed call does not work? Does the
  FileChooserButton with the Action.OPEN behaves differently from the one with
  the SELECT_FOLDER action?

Comment: When do you expect the signal to be sent, when the user clicks an item in the file list but is still working in the dialog that is opened by the button, or when the user clicks the button to dismiss the chooser dialog?

Comment: When he click the button to dismiss it.

Comment: Then you do not want to use the `selection-changed` signal; that's for when the selection in the list is changed. Instead, you want the `file-set` signal (which is specific to GtkFileChooserButton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Zee and andlabs. The answer included both suggestions.

First, the proper signal is file-set, instead of selection changed. Secondly, get_filename was catching the wrong uri format. I should've used the get_uri instead. That was the reason for operation not supported error.

Also, thanks for letting me know about the message () function, really useful.

Finally, the function should look something like:

```
    def file_changed ( file_chooser_widget: FileChooser )
    file:File = File.new_for_uri(file_chooser_widget.get_uri())
    try
        info:FileInfo = file.query_info (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE, FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, null)
        message ("after info")
        writable: bool = info.get_attribute_boolean (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE)
        if writable is false
            _entry.set_sensitive (false)
    except e: Error
        print e.message
```

Comment: Hi! 
Luís?do you have any error for this? because, I have some error for this. It is a big problem for me?!

Comment: I have some unhandled errors because the code is not complete yet. You can find the whole code in this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mfvadKDt).

Answer (score 1):

stdout is line buffered by default.

for the output, you can do these:

```
var that = "message"
print that
message (that)


stdout.printf ("%s\n", that)    // add a newline
stdout.printf (that)   // no newline, but
stdout.flush ()             // flush if no newline in that
```

a problem here:

```
var _entry = ...    // this one unvisiable in file_changed
_entry = ...        // remove var, it will visiable in file_changed
```

but I still have a problem for your code (In my machine):

**opration not supported**

```
try
    info:FileInfo = file.query_info (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE, FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, null)
    writable: bool = info.get_attribute_boolean (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE)
    if writable is true
    _entry.set_sensitive (false)

except e: Error
    print e.message // opration not supported
```

I have try to find the problem. but got nothing.