# Can't rename file because: g_file_set_display_name: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed

Tags: gtk, vala, genie

This is part of an exercise. And I couldn't find a similar question at SO. Here is a little GTK program, where after clicking the Rename button the file should be renamed.

Although the uri seems to be pointing to the correct file, for some reason I get the assertion G_IS_FILE failed at runtime.

Here is the code:

```
[indent=4]
uses
    Gtk

class TestWindow:Window
    _file_chooser:FileChooserButton
    _entry:Gtk.Entry
    _button:Gtk.Button
    _file:File

    construct()
        title = "File chooser"
        window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER
        destroy.connect( Gtk.main_quit )
        var folder_chooser = new FileChooserButton("Choose a Folder",FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)
        folder_chooser.set_current_folder( Environment.get_home_dir() )

        //I used selection_changed directly as per the question in stack_exchange
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689763/the-signal-connect-syntax
        folder_chooser.selection_changed.connect( folder_changed )

        _file_chooser = new FileChooserButton("Choose a File",FileChooserAction.OPEN)
        _file_chooser.set_current_folder( Environment.get_home_dir() )

        _file_chooser.file_set.connect( file_changed )
        _entry = new Gtk.Entry()
        _entry.set_text("Here the file name")
        //_entry.activate.connect(name_altered)

        _button = new Button.with_label("Rename")
        _button.set_sensitive(false)
        _button.clicked.connect(btn_pressed)

        var box = new Box( Orientation.VERTICAL, 0 )
        box.pack_start( folder_chooser, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _file_chooser, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _entry, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _button, true, true, 0 )
        add( box )

    def folder_changed( folder_chooser_widget:FileChooser )
        folder:string = folder_chooser_widget.get_uri()
        _file_chooser.set_current_folder_uri( folder )

    def file_changed ( file_chooser_widget: FileChooser )
        _file:File = File.new_for_uri(file_chooser_widget.get_uri())

        try
            info:FileInfo = _file.query_info (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE, FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, null)
            writable: bool = info.get_attribute_boolean (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE)
            if !writable
                _entry.set_sensitive (false)
            else
                _button.set_sensitive (true)
        except e: Error
            print e.message

        _entry.set_text(_file.get_path())

    def btn_pressed ()
        _file.set_display_name(_entry.get_text())

init
    Gtk.init( ref args )
    var test = new TestWindow()
    test.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

The problem appears at the line: `_file.set_display_name(_entry.get_text())`. I am looking for some insight on what I am doing wrong in this small Genie code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_file` is null when you call `_file.set_display_name()`.  The problem is here:

```
_file:File = File.new_for_uri(file_chooser_widget.get_uri())
```

You're creating a new variable called `_file` which shadows the `_file` field.  Changing it to

```
_file = File.new_for_uri(file_chooser_widget.get_uri())
```

should fix the issue.  Note that you could also access the field with `this._field` instead; it's a bit longer to type, but easier to read and it makes errors like this much more obvious.

Comment: Thanks nemequ, can you suggest some references where I can learn how to use this._field?