# Execl error debuging

Tags: genie

### Aim

My objective is to create a simple frontend to [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/getting-started.html). I have learned that execl is a good way of calling executables in the system.

Note in the following code the function btn_pressed, that calls pandoc using the mentioned method.

```
[indent=4]
uses
    Posix
    Gtk


class TestWindow:Window
    _file_chooser:FileChooserButton
    _entry:Gtk.Entry
    _button:Gtk.Button
    _file:File

    construct()
        title = "Pandoc GUI"
        window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER
        destroy.connect( Gtk.main_quit )
        var folder_chooser = new FileChooserButton("Choose a Folder",FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)
        folder_chooser.set_current_folder( Environment.get_home_dir() )

        //I used selection_changed directly as per the question in stack_exchange
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689763/the-signal-connect-syntax
        folder_chooser.selection_changed.connect( folder_changed )

        _file_chooser = new FileChooserButton("Choose a File",FileChooserAction.OPEN)
        _file_chooser.set_current_folder( Environment.get_home_dir() )

        _file_chooser.file_set.connect( file_changed )
        _entry = new Gtk.Entry()
        _entry.set_text("Here the file name")

        _button = new Button.with_label("Convert to pdf")
        _button.set_sensitive(false)
        _button.clicked.connect(btn_pressed)

        var box = new Box( Orientation.VERTICAL, 0 )
        box.pack_start( folder_chooser, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _file_chooser, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _entry, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _button, true, true, 0 )
        add( box )

    def folder_changed( folder_chooser_widget:FileChooser )
        folder:string = folder_chooser_widget.get_uri()
        _file_chooser.set_current_folder_uri( folder )

    def file_changed ( file_chooser_widget: FileChooser )
        _file = File.new_for_uri(file_chooser_widget.get_uri())

        try
            info:FileInfo = _file.query_info (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE, FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, null)
            writable: bool = info.get_attribute_boolean (FileAttribute.ACCESS_CAN_WRITE)
            if !writable
                _entry.set_sensitive (false)
            else
                _button.set_sensitive (true)
        except e: Error
            print e.message

        _entry.set_text(_file.get_basename())

    def btn_pressed ()
        var md_name=_entry.get_text()+".md -s -o "+_entry.get_text()+".pdf"
        execl("/usr/bin/pandoc", md_name)
        _button.set_sensitive (false)

init
    Gtk.init( ref args )
    var test = new TestWindow()
    test.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

### Error

At execution I get no response at all from my code, without any pdf being rendering as well.

### Question

- How to debug the execution of a binary with execl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `GLib.Subprocess` to call external commands because it provides better control over the input to and output from the external command. Changing the example below to `execl` should be easy enough though.

The first thing is to de-couple your external command from your window object. This makes it more testable. To do this a separate object is used - a wrapper around the `Subprocess` call. Save this code as `ToPDF.gs`:

```
namespace FileConverters

    class ToPDF

        const _command:string = "pandoc"

        def async convert( source:string, output:string )
            try
                var flags = SubprocessFlags.STDOUT_PIPE \
                            | SubprocessFlags.STDERR_PIPE
                var subprocess = new Subprocess( flags, 
                                                 _command, 
                                                 source, 
                                                 output 
                                                )
                output_buffer:Bytes
                yield subprocess.communicate_async( null, 
                                                    null,
                                                    out output_buffer, 
                                                    null 
                                                   )
                if ( subprocess.get_exit_status() == 0 )
                    debug( "command successful: \n %s",
                           (string)output_buffer.get_data() 
                          )
                else
                    debug( "command failed" )
            except err:Error
                debug( err.message )
```

The `ToPDF` class is now de-coupled from the rest of your application. This means it can be re-used. To illustrate this an integration test is shown below that uses the class.

The `ToPDF` also uses asynchronous code. So I will explain that first. Making a method asynchronous means it will run concurrently with the main thread of the application. By have a call to an external program run concurrently it means the main thread doesn't lock up while it is waiting for the external program to finish. Using `async` means the function is split in two. The first part is called with `convert.begin( source, output )` and will run up to the `yield` command. At that point the execution of the program splits in two. The main thread will return to the caller of `convert.begin`, but what has started in the background is the `Subprocess`. When the `Subprocess` finished it returns to `convert` and finishes the method call.

Save the integration test as `ToPDFTest.gs`:

```
uses FileConverters

init
    var a = new ToPDF()
    a.convert.begin( "source_file.md", "output_file.pdf" )

    var loop = new MainLoop()
    var loop_quitter = new LoopQuitter( loop )
    Timeout.add_seconds( 2, loop_quitter.quit )
    loop.run()

class LoopQuitter
    _loop:MainLoop

    construct( loop:MainLoop )
        _loop = loop

    def quit():bool
        _loop.quit()
        return false
```

Compile with `valac --pkg gio-2.0 ToPDF.gs ToPDFTest.gs`
Then run the test with `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all ./ToPDFTest`

The test uses `MainLoop`, which is the base class of `Gtk.Main`. To simulate a long running program a two second timeout is set then `MainLoop.quit()` is called to end the test. Unfortunately `MainLoop.quit()` doesn't have the right function signature for a `Timeout` callback so a wrapper class, `LoopQuitter` is used.

[Integration tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) like this are often kept and run before a software release to ensure the application is working with other software modules.

To integrate `ToPDF` with your window you need to change

`execl("/usr/bin/pandoc", md_name)`

to something like

```
var to_pdf = new Fileconverts.ToPDF()
to_pdf.convert.begin( md_name, pdf_name )
```

You may also want to wrap it in a command pattern similar to [Avoiding global variables in Genie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526346/avoiding-global-variables-in-genie) . You may also want to modify it to provide better feedback to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Absolutely clear. One doubt is regarding the begin part of convert.begin... never seen this syntax, what is it for?

Comment: It is part of making a method asynchronous. There is `convert.begin()` and also `convert.end()`, that is what I mean by the function is split in two. Both `.begin()` and `.end()` are added in the background by the Vala compiler. In this example `convert.end()` is not used because it is a simpler example.